# Is it possible to create a category list using views without taxonomy in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-8

I have a content type markets with an address field which comprises of state ,locality and postal code.I have already created a view page called markets which displays all the markets and also has a contextual filter which filters the markets based on the state mentioned in the URL as parameter.I want to create a views block which displays the state as categories and which when clicked could take me to the markets page with the clicked state as parameter so that it displays markets filtered based on states.

thank you

Comment: Have a view with a contextual filter for the state, for the block listing states, just create a view that groups the markets by state and output the state altering the link to the view. Quite simple. Why tag this question with d6,d7 and d8 ? Which are you using?

Comment: you could also use [views field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field) to simplify the output of the states block

Comment: @2pha thank you .  i am a beginner  and i wanted to know how to get the field name of the state ,so that i can use it to alter the link with a custom one which contains url of the market view page with contextual filter.
eg : /markets/{{state name}}
How do I replace this state name inthe block with states displayed based on which ever state the user clicks.

Comment: You can rewrite the output of the field. When you click on a field in the views interface, there will be a heading "REWRITE RESULTS" which you can...rewrite results, make use of tokens in there to create a link to /markets/{{state name}}